# How to loop through the dataset to group and summarise data?

Tags: r, loops

I have dataset with 5900 rows as follows:
Merged_char column is a merged column of 4 different columns with socio-demo characteristics and sum column is the sum of how many observations with each set of characteristics belong to one of 4 groups.

| Period | Group | Sum | Merged_char |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.2021 | 1st | 100 | 2_medium_North_55yo |
| 01.2021 | 2nd | 210 | 2_medium_North_55yo |
| 01.2021 | 3rd | 350 | 2_medium_North_55yo |
| 01.2021 | 4th | 170 | 2_medium_North_55yo |
| 01.2021 | 1st | 12 | 2_medium_North_20yo |
| 01.2021 | 2nd | 190 | 2_medium_North_20yo |
| 01.2021 | 3rd | 250 | 2_medium_North_20yo |
| 01.2021 | 4th | 266 | 2_medium_North_20yo |
| 01.2021 | 1st | 450 | 2_medium_South_55yo |

I want to obtain a summary with information what percentage each group represents for each combination of socio-demo. So firstly we have to calculate the sum of col "Sum" for every 4 groups: 100+210+350+170 = 830 and then use the formula for percentages like: 100/830*100 = 12% for 1st row , 210/830*100= 25,3 % etc. For the next set of Merged_char the sum of the sum column will be different, as 12+190+ 250+266= 718.
So the output should look like this:

| Period | Group | Sum | Merged_char | Percentiles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.2021 | 1st | 100 | 2_medium_North_55yo | 12,0 |
| 01.2021 | 2nd | 210 | 2_medium_North_55yo | 25,3 |
| 01.2021 | 3rd | 350 | 2_medium_North_55yo | 42,2 |
| 01.2021 | 4th | 170 | 2_medium_North_55yo | 20,4 |
| 01.2021 | 1st | 12 | 2_medium_North_20yo | 1,7 |
| 01.2021 | 2nd | 190 | 2_medium_North_20yo | 26,4 |
| 01.2021 | 3rd | 250 | 2_medium_North_20yo | 37,0 |
| 01.2021 | 4th | 266 | 2_medium_North_20yo | 37,5 |
| 01.2021 | 1st | 450 | 2_medium_South_55yo | ... |

To do that I tried to filter through group list, which have only 4 elements: 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th. Problem is with Merged_char column, because in my dataset I have 144 different combinations of it and the making the list with 144 elements is not the best way.

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df%>%
  group_by(Merged_char)%>%
  mutate(Percentile=Sum/sum(Sum,na.rm=T)*100)%>%
  ungroup


  Period Group   Sum Merged_char         Percentile
   <dbl> <fct> <int> <fct>                    <dbl>
1   1.20 1st     100 2_medium_North_55yo      12.0 
2   1.20 2nd     210 2_medium_North_55yo      25.3 
3   1.20 3rd     350 2_medium_North_55yo      42.2 
4   1.20 4th     170 2_medium_North_55yo      20.5 
5   1.20 1st      12 2_medium_North_20yo       1.67
6   1.20 2nd     190 2_medium_North_20yo      26.5 
7   1.20 3rd     250 2_medium_North_20yo      34.8 
8   1.20 4th     266 2_medium_North_20yo      37.0 
9   1.20 1st     450 2_medium_South_55yo     100
```